# How to verify that a key is loaded on a TPM 2.0 device

Tags: ubuntu, encryption, tpm

**Situation:**

I'm learning how to use some of the basic commands in the `tpm2-tools` software package because I have to develop some high-level test cases to verify a TPM is handling keys per customer requirements. The computer I'm using to demo test methods is a Dell 7510 laptop with a TPM 2.0 chip and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Since I'm entirely unfamiliar with this technology and how to use it, I'm starting by following the examples in the [help documentation](https://www.mankier.com/package/tpm2-tools).

For now, I'm focused on understanding the `tpm2_load` command and the example documented in its [help page](https://www.mankier.com/1/tpm2_load#Example). (I wrote out the process in the next section.) What I don't understand is why the key generated as a result of the `tpm2_load` command (`key_load.ctx` in my process section) is stored on the hard drive of my computer. Shouldn't it be stored on the TPM? And how can I inspect the memory of the TPM to manually verify that the key is loaded on it?

**Process:**

Below is the sequence of commands I executed, which seem to have successful:

```
$ sudo tpm2_createprimary -c key_prim.ctx
$ sudo tpm2_create -C key_prim.ctx -u key.pub -r key.priv
$ sudo tpm2_load -C key_prim.ctx -u key.pub -r key.priv -c key_load.ctx
```

I can encrypt/decrypt messages using these keys, and I can seemingly certify that `key_prim.ctx` is valid using `tpm2_certify` (by seemingly, I mean that I can execute the command and it doesn't return an error message). Everything appears to be working normally, but I'm still baffled by the fact that the key I supposedly loaded also exists on my hard drive.